# Why class name change after saving a keras model?

Tags: python, class, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

i wrote a basic keras model (tf.keras.__version = 2.2.4-tf) using tensorflow (2.0.0) :

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear',input_shape=(1,),name='equation'))
model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.save('c:\\tmp\\oneneuron')
print("Model saved type : ", type(model))
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('c:\\tmp\\oneneuron')
print("Model loaded type : ", type(loaded_model))
print("compare object model with loaded_model type : ",isinstance(model,type(loaded_model)))
print("compare object loaded_model with model type : ",isinstance(loaded_model,type(model)))
print("compare sublclass loaded_model and model type : ",issubclass(type(loaded_model),type(model)))
```

Results are

```
Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 27 2018, 03:37:03) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exec(open(r'C:\tmp\myPython\test_type_model.py').read())
2019-11-26 18:49:39.071088: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2019-11-26 18:49:39.574113: W tensorflow/python/util/util.cc:299] Sets are not currently considered sequences, but this may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W1126 18:49:39.627490 11772 deprecation.py:506] From F:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py:1781: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
Model saved type :  <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>
Model loaded type :  <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model.load.Sequential'>
compare object model with loaded_model type :  False
compare object loaded_model with model type :  True
compare sublclass loaded_model and model type :  True
```

Where can I find the difference between tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model.load.Sequential and tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential in tensorflow or keras documentation?

Answer (score -1):

Not really a proper answer, but I wanted to add what I have found out on this issue (which is really puzzling me):

- I couldn't find any documentation on it
- using h5 format solved the problem for me: model.save('c:\tmp\oneneuron.h5')
- the changed object type really caused problems for me, e.g. model.layers[i].filters would work before but not after saving and reloading.

My tensorflow version is 2.1